# electron-builder : remove locales from production in windows platform

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

From this link:
https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration

It says we have this option:

> electronLanguages Array | String - The electron locales to keep. By default, all Electron locales used as-is.

But apparently `electronLanguages` just works for `mac` platform(As is it in this [boilerplate](https://github.com/chef/chef-workstation-app/blob/main/electron-builder.yml))

But no matter where I put this option, this option does not work for `win` platform:

```json
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.electron-serial",
    "electronLanguages": ["en_US"], // I tested here
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "msi"
      ],
      "icon": "./icon/logo.png",
    "electronLanguages": ["en_US"], // I tested here
    },
    "msi": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "perMachine": true,
      "electronLanguages": ["en_US"], // I tested here
    }
  },
  "electronLanguages": ["en_US"], // I tested here
```

Comment: For me this worked fine (on the same level as `appId`), but I specified the locale as  "en-US" (using _dash_ not underscore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`win` platform does not support `electronLanguages` option.
I found this work around in this [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18738#issuecomment-511704668):

> When using electron-builder, you can default to the locale en-US via
> `app.commandLine.appendSwitch('lang', 'en-US'); // before app.on('ready', ...)`
> and remove the unused locales from your electron project via the "afterPack" hook in the package.json
> `"build": { "afterPack": "./removeLocales.js", ... }`
> which could look like
>
> ```js
> //https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#afterpack
> exports.default = async function(context) {   //console.log(context)
>   var fs = require('fs');     var localeDir =
> context.appOutDir+'/locales/';
>
>   fs.readdir(localeDir, function(err, files){         //files is array of
> filenames (basename form)         if(!(files && files.length)) return;        for
> (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {           var match =
> files[i].match(/en-US\.pak/);             if(match === null){
>               fs.unlinkSync(localeDir+files[i]);          }       }   }); }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`"electronLanguages"` has been moved to global config. It now supports Windows/Linux.

electron-builder>=24.2.0

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/pull/7516